# Laravel 4 - Method [where] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to get row from the table with "->find(X)" or "->where" but i get error in return. i guess i am missing something but i can't tell what.

```
<?php

class SnippetsController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;

    public function index($id)
    {
        $snippet = SnippetsController::where('id', '=', 11)->get();
```

i tried it with find but noting helps.

```
    $snippet = SnippetsController::find(11);
```

with "->get" and without. but noting works. i do have the "11" id in the table itself and the error seems to have noting to do with it.

maybe i need to extend the class to Eloquent? if so, how do i keep the BaseController on top of it?

Thanks!

error:

> BadMethodCallException Method [find] does not exist.

Comment: You probably should be calling that on a model...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a Model called Snippet, right? So this is how you use it:

```
$snippet = Snippet::find(11);
```

Your `SnippetsController` is not tied to a database (Eloquent ORM), so you must create (if you don't have already) a model:

```
class Snippet extends Eloquent {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the code `$snippet = SnippetsController::where('id', '=', 11)->get();` with `$snippet = Snippets::where('id', '=', 11)->get();`. May be your model name is `Snippets` it may solve your problem.